# What is the purpose of the capacitor and resistor in this op-amp circuit?

Tags: capacitor, operational-amplifier, resistors, audio

Here is the op-amp circuit, which is found in [this](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/24125.pdf) datasheet on page 5:
[image]

I have boxed, in red, the part of the circuit that I am confused about. What is the point of having this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Jippies says. The Boucherot cell (seen here) is a spacial case of Zoebel networks which are a matching network aimed at transforming the impedance of a frequency variable "target" to make the overall result more like a pure resistance with a wider flatter frequency response.  For too much detail see [Wikipedia - Zoebel network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobel_network)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a [Zobel network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobel_network#Zobel_networks_and_loudspeaker_drivers) also known as [Boucherot cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boucherot_cell), meant to stablize the amplifier when no load (speaker) is attached. It compensates the increasing speaker impedance at higher frequencies and prevents high frequency oscillation.

Answer (score 11):

(1) What Jippies says.

(2) The Boucherot cell (seen here) is a special case of a Zoebel network.
Zoebel networks are a matching network aimed at transforming the impedance of a frequency variable "target" to make the overall result more like a pure resistance with a wider flatter frequency response.  For too much detail see [Wikipedia - Zoebel network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobel_network).

For speaker application see section "Zobel networks and loudspeaker drivers".
In the speaker application the component between the centre of the RC and the speakers notional LR is missing (as the speaker's distributed LR has no physical tap - and you can swap R & C so it is no longer a Zobel bridge but still works.

**Interest:**

Original 1923 paper is : Zobel, O. J., Theory and Design of Uniform and Composite Electric Wave Filters, Bell Systems Technical Journal, Vol. 2 (1923), pp. 1–46.

Image of full 1923 article here:
<strike>http://alcatel-lucent.com/bstj/vol02-1923/articles/bstj2-1-1.pdf</strike> Link now dead.
https://archive.org/details/bstj2-1-1

Munted text version here:
http://archive.org/stream/bellsystemtechni02amerrich/bellsystemtechni02amerrich_djvu.txt

Original title is "Theory and Design of Uniform and Composite 
Electric Wave-filters"

Zoebel is spelt Zobel in the paper.

---

1st page of original here

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/j.1538-7305.1923.tb00001.x/abstract

**47 pages of original here -**

Online viewable:   https://archive.org/details/bstj2-1-1

Downloadable PDF:  https://ia801902.us.archive.org/8/items/bstj2-1-1/bstj2-1-1.pdf

Comment: Interesting background information!

Comment: @SamGibson - thanks for link edits. As a result of your input I found the full original paper - see above

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - No worries :-) I linked to the "main" page for the paper on archive.org to allow readers to choose the format that they wanted, from the list provided there. Obviously I'll defer to whatever link you want to put instead of my edit, if you want to change that :-) Thanks for the interesting answer! (+1)

Comment: @SamGibson - I dislike increasing entropy in answers (although some argue that when I answer at all that that can be what happens :-). So, leaving your links and mine is fine by me. Alas, some others sometimes disagree.